# How are scripts imported?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I've installed Angular for trying this out. I have `node.js` installed with `npm`, and I installed the `@angular/cli` package globally. Then I did: `ng new testproject`. I now have all the files installed. I did `npm install` and `npm start` and everything worked, even the app said so! (LOL).

Now, when I look into the files and see the index.html file in my `./src`, there is not a lot of stuff going on.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Testproject</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

This feels strange. Angular is made with JavaScript (compiled Typescript). But when I look at the developer tools in Google Chrome, I can see that there are actually script tags inside my html.

Can someone explain me how these files got here? What is happening on the server-side, and which files make this happen? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `<base href="/">` is the reference your looking for. If you build(ng build --prod), it will reference all the default complied scripts to this path, in the default case being root of your application.

Comment: I don't think that is what they are asking.  They are asking how there are scripts running on the page at all, when there is no `<script>` tag in the HTML.

Comment: When you build, it create them from that base. example <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.cd21f8097fbc8b0a4679.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.ebc9a0e6cbaec66d1946.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.b80c0b42c581ccdb64bb.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.97117256ca0f539c2a53.bundle.js"></script>

Comment: Does it always build the project when you request it?